# Move container div until find certain child

Tags: jquery, html

I need to move a div parent horizontally, until an specific child gets visible, considering that there is an order, first child1, then child2, and finally child3. I am planning to do this by adding buttons for going left and right. So this like a slider i am trying to build by my self, how can I achieve this by using `animate` jquery function, or maybe other solution.

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px;overflow:hidden" >
     <div id="parent" style="width:1500px">
         <div id="child1" style="width:500px;float:left">
         </div>
         <div id="child2" style="width:500px;float:left">
         </div>
         <div id="child2" style="width:500px;float:left">
         </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (removed your inline styling and added it as CSS to see better)

Code snippet:

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  $("#parent").animate({
    "left": "0px"
  });

});

$(".btn2").click(function() {
  $("#parent").animate({
    "left": "-500px"
  });

});

$(".btn3").click(function() {
  $("#parent").animate({
    "left": "-1000px"
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#parent {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
}

#child2 {
  background: red;
}

#child3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="box" id="child1"></div>
    <div class="box" id="child2"></div>
    <div class="box" id="child3"></div>
  </div>

</div>


<button class="btn1">slide 1</button>
<button class="btn2">slide 2</button>
<button class="btn3">slide 3</button>
```

Comment: nice!, but what if i want just two buttons, right and left (or add them to what you've  already done )

Comment: @Flezcano you would just have to adjust the code. This is not meant to be dynamic but it's a good base to build upon and it could be dynamic if needed.

Comment: thanks man! you are right!, that's all I need, i will modify it!

Comment: @Flezcano No problem. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved for future use?